# PHP - function which initializes variables

Tags: php, function, variables

I would like to make cross variables in my template via the router.

I want to do:

```
$router->with(array(...));
```

Here is my with function:

```
public function with($vars)
{
    if(is_array($vars))
    {
        foreach ($vars as $key => $value)
        {
           $$key = $value;
        }
    }else
    {
        die("La fonction with() demande un tableau en paramètre.");
    }
}
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: I wouldn't create all those variables. Just use the array and access the data with the key.

Comment: utterly useless, since those variables would exist ONLY within your `with()` function, and be destroyed as soon as the function exits.

Comment: yeah, I forgot the extract() function. Everything is revised and functional, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead just extract your keys as vars in your template. Like this

```
function with($view, array $data = []) {
    extract($data);
    require $view . '.php';
}

with('some_view', [
    'name' => 'John Doe'
]);
```

Then you can use it in your view, like so

```
<h1><?= $name ?></h1>
```